# How do I rescale an align environment on a beamer slide?

Tags: beamer, amsmath, align, scaling

I'm trying to resize an equation on a `beamer` slide to make it larger. However, the usual approach of using `\scalebox` doesn't seem to work:

```
\begin{frame}
\scalebox{2}{
\begin{align}
  x &= y\\
  y &= z
\end{align}
}
\end{frame}
```

Producing the following error:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup
```

How do I rescale an align environment on a beamer slide?

Comment: Add `\Huge` just before it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`align` adjusts its contents based on the available width (in order to place it horizontally in the centre, and to place the appropriate tags/numbering). Inserting it inside a `\scalebox` causes the problem that there's no defined box to contain it. However, if you provide such a containment, it scales without problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
  x &= y\\
  y &= z
\end{align}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\scalebox{2}{\parbox{.5\linewidth}{%
\begin{align}
  x &= y\\
  y &= z
\end{align}
}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Off topic: I am curious why `beamer.cls` which is not a package is hosted in `pkg` directory of `ctan.org`? Theoretically it should be placed in `ctan.org/cls`. :-)

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction: Yes. There are many such examples: [`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran), [`AMS-LaTeX`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amslatex) - a collection of packages and classes, [`math-mode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode), [`texbook`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook) and [TeX by Topic](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) which are documents only, ... It may just be a [database (filename) structure](http://www.ctan.org/help/access/package) that they've stuck to in order to ease retrieval of information.

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction "package" at ctan is a package in the sense of a package manager for linux (or tex live) a group of related _files_. The use is different (and predates) the use of "package" for latex which is a file containing a group of related _commands_.

Comment: @Werner This way the equations inside the align environment are not in display mode any more. Any idea how to fix that other than manually leaving blank lines before and after the `\scalebox` and center all this stuff?