# Rescaling equation in align+split environment - Numbering problem

Tags: numbering, align, split

I'm trying to rescale my to long equation in align + split environment (to get only one numbering). I found a method from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166193/how-do-i-rescale-an-align-environment-on-a-beamer-slide) which is pretty useful.

However, the numbering is altered and is indicated below the equations instead of at the right. I guess it's due to the `\parbox` command but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is a MWE, with a long equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{0.8}{\parbox{.5\linewidth}{%
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
C_{M,i}(x) = &-\frac{e^{\text{Ha}_{i} - x \, \frac{k}{D_{\text{NO},t}}}\left(\left(-1 + e^{\text{H\~{a}}_{i}}\right)\left(-1+\text{Mu}_{i}+e^{\text{H\~{a}}_{i}}(1+\text{Mu}_{i})\right) \, Pr + 2 \, e^{\text{H\~{a}}_{i}} \, k \, \lambda_{\text{air},i} \, C_{i}(t,z) \right)}{2 \, k \left(-1 + \text{Mu}_{i} + e^{2 \, (\text{Ha}_{i}+\text{H\~{a}}_{i})}(1+\text{Mu}_{i})\right)} \\
&+\frac{e^{\text{Ha}_{i} + x \, \frac{k}{D_{\text{NO},t}}}\left(\left(-1+e^{\text{H\~{a}}_{i}}\right)\left(-1+\text{Mu}_{i} + e^{\text{H\~{a}}_{i}}(1+\text{Mu}_{i})\right) \, Pr + 2 \, e^{\text{H\~{a}}_{i}} \, k \, \lambda_{\text{air},i} \, C_{i}(t,z)\right)}{2 \, k \, \left(-1+\text{Mu}_{i} + e^{2(\text{Ha}_{i} + \text{H\~{a}}_{i})}(1+\text{Mu}_{i})\right)}
\end{split}
\end{align}
}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to scale equations but if you do it this way you are scaling after the number is added so if the equation number is moved because of the long equation, the scaling will not change that it just makes it bigger.  But please fix the example so it is a complete example that people can run to see the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I corrected the example with a long enough equation

Comment: I made it a proper example that shows the problem, but as I said in the first comment the `\scalebox`  isn't changing the positioning of the equation number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to scale the equations, do it properly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\resizebox{.8\textwidth}{!}{%
  $\begin{aligned}
   C_{M,i}(x) ={}
   & -\frac{
        e^{\mathrm{Ha}_{i} - x \frac{k}{D_{\mathrm{NO},t}}}
        \bigl(
          (-1 + e^{\mathrm{H\tilde{a}}_{i}})(-1+\mathrm{Mu}_{i} +
            e^{\mathrm{H\tilde{a}}_{i}}(1+\mathrm{Mu}_{i}))Pr +
          2e^{\mathrm{H\tilde{a}}_{i}} k\lambda_{\mathrm{air},i}  C_{i}(t,z)
        \bigr)
      }{
        2k(-1 + \mathrm{Mu}_{i} + e^{2(\mathrm{Ha}_{i}+\mathrm{H\tilde{a}}_{i})}(1+\mathrm{Mu}_{i}))
      }
   \\
   & +\frac{
        e^{\mathrm{Ha}_{i} + x \frac{k}{D_{\mathrm{NO},t}}}
        \bigl(
          (-1+e^{\mathrm{H\tilde{a}}_{i}})(-1+\mathrm{Mu}_{i} +
           e^{\mathrm{H\tilde{a}}_{i}}(1+\mathrm{Mu}_{i}))Pr +
          2e^{\mathrm{H\tilde{a}}_{i}}  k\lambda_{\mathrm{air},i}  C_{i}(t,z))
      }{
        2k(-1+\mathrm{Mu}_{i} + e^{2(\mathrm{Ha}_{i} + \mathrm{H\tilde{a}}_{i})}(1+\mathrm{Mu}_{i}))
     }
  \end{aligned}$%
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed all `\left` and `\right`; also all `\,` commands (they were wrong). I only used `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` in the outermost parentheses of the big expressions.

Don't use `\text`, but `\mathrm` in this context.

Comment: How would one need to change this code if one wants every line to get its own number? (1) and (2)

Answer (score 2):

I think you (and even more the readers of your document) would be better off if you didn't scale down the equation to make it fit inside the text block. Instead, consider using the `\splitdfrac` macro, which is provided by the `mathtools` package, to split the long numerator terms into two parts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'splitdfrac'  environment
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
C_{M,i}(x) 
&=      -\frac{\left(\splitdfrac{e^{\textrm{Ha}_i - x \frac{k}{D_{\textrm{NO},t}}}
\bigl[(-1+e^{\textrm{H\~{a}}_i})(-1+\textrm{Mu}_i}{+e^{\textrm{H\~{a}}_i}(1+\textrm{Mu}_i)) Pr 
+ 2e^{\textrm{H\~{a}}_i} k \lambda_{\textrm{air},i} C_i(t,z) \bigr]}\right)}{ \displaystyle
2k \bigl[ -1+\textrm{Mu}_i + e^{2(\textrm{Ha}_i+\textrm{H\~{a}}_i)}
(1+\textrm{Mu}_i) \bigr]} \\[2ex]
&\quad +\frac{\left(\splitdfrac{e^{\textrm{Ha}_i + x \frac{k}{D_{\textrm{NO},t}}}
\bigl[(-1+e^{\textrm{H\~{a}}_i})(-1+\textrm{Mu}_i}{+e^{\textrm{H\~{a}}_i}(1+\textrm{Mu}_i)) Pr 
+ 2e^{\textrm{H\~{a}}_i} k \lambda_{\textrm{air},i} C_i(t,z) \bigr]}\right)}{ \displaystyle
2k \bigl[ -1+\textrm{Mu}_i + e^{2(\textrm{Ha}_i+\textrm{H\~{a}}_i)}
(1+\textrm{Mu}_i) \bigr]}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```